# Wierd behavior Microsoft Excel when opening xls file (which is in fact an html file)

Tags: microsoft-excel, html

I have an file with the extension .xls, however in fact it is an .html file. See also https://superuser.com/a/1103930/201762 (the provided answer doesn't work for me)

Now on my computer I cannot open the file with Excel, you will have to rename the file extension to .html or .txt or something similar. I only get 'OK' as option;
[image]

With another computer I can open the file, it namely gives me the option to still open the file;
[image]

**What is going on here? How can I ensure that on my first computer I get the same warning message and can still open the file?**

Content of the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the same version of Excel/Office installed on both computers?

Comment: No unfortunatly not. I did check however if the computer with the problem has the Windows Updates installed, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the source of the difference between the two dialogs
is that they are not produced by the same version of Office.

I can duplicate the second dialog (that you want) in my Office 365.
It might also be the same in the (almost) equivalent Office 2021.

The version of Office on your computer might be an earlier
version. You need to install Office 365 to have the same behavior.